# Don't show numbers is y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a ggplot plot

Is there any simple way to not show in y-axis the scores?

For example something to  `+ ()`?

Comment: Do you want to disable axis labels?

Comment: Just change all the "x"s to "y"s in the other answer.

Comment: @slava-kohut yes not all labels only in yaxis

Comment: @foc use `+theme(axis.title.y=element_blank())`

Comment: @slava-kohut thank you very much